# Can not show uploaded image with CKEditor when editor and upload action file live on seperate server

Tags: ckeditor

I tried upload image with CKEditor form ASP.net server and send image to upload with PHP in another server.

That's work for upload image but the image didn't show on editor.

Please could you help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use different servers due to cross-site scripting protection by the browser. Check this sample: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=46715#p46715